# Как объяснить выбор суффикса ЕВА в глаголе "продлевать"?

Tags: орфография

Мне на форуме попалось объяснение, причем довольно путаное, где упоминается некое правило:

"С этим словом все просто. Оно **не подчиняется правилу**: если глагол оканчивается на ударную -ить, -ваю, то перед суффиксом -ва- нужно ставить ту же гласную, что и в неопределенной форме глагола без этого суффикса. Не подчиняется потому что это слово -- исключение, как и некоторые другие слова: затмить - затмевать, застрять - застревать; продлить - продлевать".

В правилах Лопатина  объяснение по этой теме также не из простых.

А можно объяснить выбор ЕВА **просто, понятно и желательно без исключений** в глаголах затмевать, продлевать, растлевать, застревать  и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Застрять - исключите сразу. Оно ***подчиняется*** правилу. Основное правило, если его так формулировать, таково, что "ева" пишется всегда, когда н.ф. не "ить", но согласная мягкая. Но это все равно плохая формулировка. Не тащите бездумно сюда всякие формулировки с разных форумов. Хорошая - у меня абзацем ниже.

А вот что касается остальных исключений, то да, они есть, и как можно объяснить **исключения** без исключений - непонятно.

На самом деле куда удобнее смотреть по первому лицу единственного числа.

[Написание суффиксов -ОВА-, -ЕВА-, -ИВА-, -ЫВА- | raal100.narod.ru](http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-133)

> **Если в 1-м лице настоящего времени глагол оканчивается на -ую, -юю, то в неопределенной форме и в прошедшем времени пишется -ОВА-, -ЕВА-** 
>   беседую – беседовать, беседовал (а не беседывать, беседывал)
>   воюю – воевать, воевал (а не воивать, воивал)
>
> **Если в 1-м лице настоящего времени глагол оканчивается на -ываю, -иваю без ударения на -А-, то в неопределенной форме и в прошедшем времени пишется -ЫВА-, -ИВА-**
>   рассказываю – рассказывать, рассказывал (а не рассказовать, рассказовал)
>   рассматриваю – рассматривать, рассматривал (а не рассматревать, рассматревал)
>
> **Если в суффиксе ударение падает на -А-, то пишется -ЕВА-**
>   одолева́ть, одолева́ю (а не одолива́ть, одолива́ю)

Сюда же, к последнему, и все ваши сложности.
затмев**А**ю - затм**е**вать.
застрев**А**ю - зестр**е**вать.
продлев**А**ю - продл**е**вать.

> В правилах Лопатина объяснение по этой теме также не из простых.

Ссылочкой не поделитесь, раз уж упомянули? Что Вам там непонятно, простейшая же тема.

Comment: (1) Формулировка с другого форума  не бездумна, она показывает, как российские пользователи понимают эту тему и что у них в голове.  (2) У Лопатина: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=34#pp34  § 61, 62, формулировки  значительно отличаются от ваших. (3) Я приведу в своем ответе вариант, который в принципе совпадает с Вашим, но с некоторыми уточнениями.